# How to test a battery the alternative way?

Tags: battery, testing

Aside from buying a battery tester, is there any other way to check it? I presume under full load with the engine, lights, etc.

Comment: Get yourself a multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the battery in the vehicle with the engine running won't tell you about only the condition of the battery but the charging and electrical system too.

If you don't want to buy a battery meter, I'd suggesting driving the vehicle to a local repair garage or motor spares reseller as most will offer an either inexpensive or free battery health check.